# EF Core - Connect two tables with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I've two EF Core entities that I want to connect over a string-key, that doesn't follow the id-name-convention. And a simple DbContext like this:

```
public DbSet<Entity1> Table1 { get; set; }
public DbSet<Entity2> Table2 { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Entity2) 
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey<Entity1>(s => s.Name); 
}

public class Entity1
{
    public String Name{ get; set; }
    public Entity2 Entity2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2
{
    [Key]
    public String Nummer { get; set; }
}
```

It doesn't throw any errors - but querying data, the "Entity2" property is always null - even if there is a dataset in Table2, where "Nummer" is equal the "Name" value of Entity1.

I also tries the ForeignKey-Attribute without the OnModelCreating-Code - but with the same results.

I think, there is a complete misunderstanding of myself of the foreign key concept in EF core.

Are there any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be in the query process. How do you query the data. EFCore does not make a join query by default unless you specify it explicitly through `Include()`. For example,

```cs
var entity1 = db.Table1
    .Where(x=>x.Name == "test")
    .Include(x=>x.Entity2)     <--- watch this
    .First();
```

`Include(x=>x.Entity2)` specify that there is a join query between two tables, and the returned `Entity1` object contains the data of `Entity2`.

Comment: That was the point :-) I thought there would be something magic in EF Core doing this include for me ;-) Thanks so much.